# SQLite - include database without the full path ( getResource() )

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an SQLite database inside my **project/src/main/resources/database** folder named database.sqlite.

How can I add properly the connection (DriverManager.getConnection() ) without adding the full path with the getResource() method? Now it's look like:

```
public static Connection Connector() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:../project/src/main/resources/database/database.sqlite");
        return conn;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return null;
```

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general accessing a SQLight database via `getResource()` is a strange way especially when the application is shipped as jar or war. 
So if possible think of use a property or configuration to retrieve the path of the database file.

If it's a requirement to access the SQLight Database file via class path and  `getResource()` you can do it the following way, at least when it is outside of a jar/war. This approach will *not work* for a database file shipped as part of a jar.

```
URL resource = YourClass.class.getResource("database.sqlite");
String path = new File(resource.toURI()).getAbsolutePath(); 

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:sqlite:%s",path));
```

For this to work "database.sqlite" must be in the class path.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say that, but your approach is totally wrong.

Putting some resource files like images, read-only property files, etc. in the classpath is ok. These can simply be read by an `InputStream` obtained by `getResourceAsStream()`, even if they last inside a JAR eventually.

But a SQLite database file has internal structures for which the driver needs random access (like [`RandamAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in Java). Additionally you may want to write to it, too. This is all not possible if the database file is contained inside a JAR.

So you should put the database file directly somewhere in the filesystem.